# Magento 2 : the JS messages do not translated!

Tags: magento2, js-translation

I use magento 2.0 and I have a problem.

The JS messages of fields control do not translated (like Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com). or Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored.)

This is a sample:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was reported: see this bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4883

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1) magento 2.0.5 (test - true)***

```
lib/web/mage/validation.js
```

***line 246 :***

```
replace : 'Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).'
$.mage.__('Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).')
2) Del. static : pub/static/ (only dir) and var/view_preprocessed/
```

Comment: Have you verified this issue with upstream? E.g. is this reported? If so can you please provide a link or a ticket number? That would be tremendously great.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this Magento bug, I copy the file `lib/web/mage/validation.js` to my theme and translated it there.

So, the translated file is in: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/mage/validation.js`

Comment: app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/mage/validation.js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct changes in js. Make csv as per locale Ex: app/design/frontend///i18n/de_DE.csv(locale name).

Ex:

"You can create an account after checkout.","Sie können nach dem Auschecken ein Konto erstellen."

"Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid.","Die angegebene Postleitzahl scheint ungültig zu sein."

" Example: "," Beispiel: "

"If you believe it is the right one you can ignore this notice.","Wenn Sie glauben, dass es das richtige ist, können Sie diesen Hinweis ignorieren."

Run the following commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

Now refresh the page with Ctrl + F5.

Now you can see js messages are translated